# On Mouse Over Not Showing Image

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, onmouseover, asplinkbutton

The following code only executes the color change.  I never see the image.

I am writing this in C# ASP.Net in Visual Studio 2017

Basically tried variations of this code.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Font-Underline="true" runat="server" 
 OnMouseOver="mouseOver();" OnMouseOut="mouseOut();">Facility 
 ID</asp:LinkButton> 
 <img src="../Images/invoice.PNG" id="image1" alt="Image Not Found" 
 width="1000" height="500" style="display:none;" runat="server" /> 


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 document.getElementById("LinkButton1").onmouseover = function() 
 {mouseOver()};
 document.getElementById("LinkButton1").onmouseout = function() 
 {mouseOut()};

 function mouseOver() {
 document.getElementById("LinkButton1").style.color = "red";
 document.getElementById("LinkButton1").style.display="inline";
 document.getElementById("LinkButton1").src = '../Images/invoice.PNG';
 }

 function mouseOut() {
 document.getElementById("LinkButton1").style.color = "black";
 }
 </script>
```

I expect to see the image show like a callout or popup.  The text changes to red and the page only indicates javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1','')

Comment: When you say that you are seeing the color change is it changing to both red and black? Also is the src of the url being updated and there is no image being displayed or is the src value not being updated?

Comment: Yes the color changes to red when I mouse over and back to black when I mouse out.  Not sure what you mean by the url being updated.  The url is or should be a static reference to the Images folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may see your issue. 
On this line

```
document.getElementById("LinkButton1").src = '../Images/invoice.PNG';
```

you appear to be trying to update the src of the button and not the image.

Try updating your code to use the id of the img tag like this

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = '../Images/invoice.PNG';
```

**EDIT1**
Ok I am adding in now so when you mouseover the button the image is available and when you mouse out the image goes away. I am doing this using the css visibility property.We set the image to hidden by default inline on the element using the style attribute. When you mouseover the button we set the visible property to visible and when you mouse out we set it back to hidden.

Here is the code to do so

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button1">Button</button>
    <img id="image1" src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/025.png" style="visibility: hidden;"></img>
</body>
<script>
    function mouseOver(){
        document.getElementById('button1').style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById('button1').style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    function mouseOut(){
        document.getElementById('button1').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    document.getElementById('button1').onmouseover = mouseOver;
    document.getElementById('button1').onmouseout = mouseOut;
</script>
</html>
```

I have also updated the gitub example with the new code and placed it into a file title index2.html which you can view [here](https://github.com/fk1018/so/blob/master/57612879/index2.html).

Comment: I created an example repository mimicking your code and providing a solution. 
Let me know if it works for you or if there are still issues. https://github.com/fk1018/so/tree/master/57612879

Comment: I can get your code to work, but my goal is to show the image when a person mouses over the linkbutton.

Comment: Cool do you want the image to be the background of the button or would you like the image to be visible when the button is moused over. Also do you want the image to still be visible when a user mouse outs?

Comment: Only visible with the button is moused over.

Comment: Sweet thanks for clarifying @crystalnoob . I have updated my answer above to hide and show the image accordingly now I think. Please let me know if this is still not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A LinkButton, which simply is an anchor in html does not have a `src` property. It is not an image. Use a background image.

```
document.getElementById("LinkButton1").style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png')";
```

OR change it to an ImageButton Control, which becomes `<input type="image"`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the imagebutton control.  Do I still use the function?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, everyone.  Between your suggestions and some tinkering, I was able to get the code to work as expected.

Here is the final code.  When I hover over the linkbutton the image shows below the button and disappears when I mouse out.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Font-Underline="true" runat="server" 
OnMouseOver="mouseOver();" OnMouseOut="mouseOut();">Facility ID</asp:LinkButton>

function mouseOver() {

document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("image1").style.backgroundimage = "input type=image";
}

function mouseOut()
{

document.getElementById("image1").style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("[id*=GrdEmplistAtt] img").elevateZoom({
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    imageCrossfade: true,
                    loadingIcon: 'loading.gif'
                });
            });
        </script>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Files" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="300px"
                                                                                        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblGrdDocFileName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("DocFileName") %>' CssClass="form-label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                                            <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                                                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="30px" ImageAlign="Middle" Visible="false" />
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                                                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="30px" Visible="false" ImageAlign="Middle" />
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                                                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="30px" Visible="false" ImageAlign="Middle" />
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                                                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="30px" Visible="false" ImageAlign="Middle" />
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="250"></ItemStyle>
                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/541191/Display-GridView-image-in-Modal-Popup-on-MouseOver-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet/ follow this link also

Comment: https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/541191/Display-GridView-image-in-Modal-Popup-on-MouseOver-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet/